# Custom cell tableview and default UITableView in one UIViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UIViewController with two UITableViews,one custom cell XIB tableview and another default dynamic tableview.The custom cell tableview fires its delegate but the other table view doesn't .Here is my code

```
@interface Question : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
```

And .m

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if(tableView == _similarTable)
    {
tableCell =(SimilarQuestion *)[_similarTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"similarTable"];

if(tableCell == nil)
    {
tableCell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"SimilarQuestion" owner:self options:Nil]objectAtIndex:0];

    }
if(finalAskerArray!=nil && finalQuesArray.count >0)
    {
tableCell.questionText.text= [finalQuesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
tableCell.lblAsker.text=[finalAskerArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
    }
    return tableCell;
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"==>Hit");
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"categoryTable"];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"categoryTable" owner:self options:nil]objectAtIndex:0];            
    }
    if(popCategoryArray != nil && popCategoryArray.count >0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = [popCategoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
    return cell;
}
}
```

And I call the default table view on click of a button ,the code on button click as below

```
-(IBAction)catBtnPressed:(id)sender{if(categoryArray.count !=0)    {
popCategoryArray = categoryArray;
    categoryView = [[UIView  alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320 , 548)];
    categoryTable.delegate   = self;
    categoryTable.dataSource =self ;
            [UIView transitionWithView:categoryView duration:2.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                    animations:^{
                        [self.view addSubview:categoryView];
                    }     completion:NULL];

    categoryTable  = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 240)];
       [categoryTable reloadData];
    [categoryView addSubview:categoryTable];
    [self.view addSubview:categoryView];

}
```

}

The [categoryTable reloadData] never calls the delegate. Where am I going  wrong?

Comment: did you set categoryTables delegate?

Comment: yes check the -(IBAction)catBtnPressed

Comment: is `catBtnPressed:` wired up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set dataSource and delegate of UITableView its init method.

```
-(IBAction)catBtnPressed:(id)sender{if(categoryArray.count !=0)    {
popCategoryArray = categoryArray;
    categoryView = [[UIView  alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320 , 548)];
    [UIView transitionWithView:categoryView duration:2.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromTop
                    animations:^{
                        [self.view addSubview:categoryView];
                    }     completion:NULL];

    categoryTable  = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 240)];
    categoryTable.delegate = self; //move from above
    categoryTable.dataSource = self; //move from above
    [categoryTable reloadData];
    [categoryView addSubview:categoryTable];
    [self.view addSubview:categoryView]; //You have addSubview:categoryView in above UIView animation, maybe should not add here

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you are setting `categoryTable.delegate` before you set `categoryTable`.  It's hard to figure out what was meant, but this doesn't seem right.

Taking some excerpts from your code, it's not clear what `categoryTable` is supposed to be set to here, where you set the delegate:

```
categoryTable.delegate   = self;
```

then a few lines later you set `categoryTable` to a new object and add it to the view:

```
categoryTable  = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320, 240)];
   [categoryTable reloadData];
[categoryView addSubview:categoryTable];
```

so for that instance of UITableView you haven't set the delegate at the point that `reloadData` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Before call `categoryTable.reload()` ,first make sure your `categoryTable`'s `delegate` property and `dataSource` property refer to your controller,for example :

```
categoryTable.delegate = self ;
categoryTable.dataSource ＝ self ;
```

`self` is the UIViewController whose view contains `categoryTable`, in you code , `self` is `Question` controller.

Comment: check the -(IBAction)catBtnPressed method I have declared it